# The request was redirected to 'https://..com/site/login?', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, http, cors

Before posting this question i have gone through most of the stack overflow questions but i didnt got an answer

i am trying access an client api which will do Oauth authentication so when i call the api it should thrown an popup window for authentication similar to fb auth,but i am ending up with error in my chrome console like below

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.springrole.com/authorize?
>   scope=XXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/CheckRest/springrole.html&response_type=XXXX&client_id=XXXXXXXX.
>   The request was redirected to
>   'https://springrole.com/site/login?api_login=1&scope=XXXX&state=&error=invalid_request',
>   which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

i have just masked some of the values with XXX for safety purpose. and my req looks like below

```
 $http({
        method : 'GET',

        url : url,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://api.springrole.com",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
        }
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.details.response = JSON.stringify(data);

        console.log("success" + data)
    })
```

if i remove the headers in the request i am getting the below shown error

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

any suggestions or work around will be appreciated.

Comment: The access control headers are usually supposed to be added automatically by the browser rather than set by you explicitly. Have you tried removing them?

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan if i remove them i got the below error  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: This method of adding the header client side is interesting. Typically, I've seen the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set server side to control access to a given resource...

Comment: @War10ck someone suggested to try having the headers in client end so i just tried .

Comment: See the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949492/cors-request-with-preflight-and-redirect-disallowed-workarounds/39728229#39728229 for details of how to work around this. Also as noted there, this restriction on redirects is no longer in the spec but browsers need to update their implementations to match the spec change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you're running into the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) which is in place for security reasons. In a nutshell, it's basically you're requesting/opening something from a different origin which isn't very secure. If you want, you can disable it temporarily in Chrome by adding the argument `--disable-web-security`.

So from Terminal you can run

`open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security`

I do it often so I ended up just adding and alias to my `.bash_profile` so I can access it easily

```
# Run Insecure Chrome
alias insecure-chrome='open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security'
```

Then in Terminal I can just call `insecure-chrome` and Chrome will pop up. You'll know it worked if you see the Security warning at the top. The warning looks like this

[image]

And **of course obligatory warning be careful when doing this**. I would not surf the web in this mode but working locally you should be fine.

For windows users you can navigate to the folder where Chrome is installed and set

> chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/temp" --disable-web-security

Make sure to close all Chrome instances before doing this or else it won't work.